# WooCommerce - Checkout suddenly stops working

Tags: loop, jquery, woocommerce-offtopic, reset

From one day to the next apparently the **checkout**, specifically **selecting a payment option** stopped working.
I can't figure out why, but when selecting an option, the page **keeps jQuery reloading**.

**this is the site:** [site link](http://www.easy2work.at)

I tried switching themes but the error persists even with the Twenty Fifteen Theme.

**If anyone knows what the cause of this might be, please help!!**

in case you need access: wp-admin with tempadmin (user) and easy123work as Password.
This error just started today and apparently for no reason.

**Help is very much appreciated!!**

**edit01:** I've reverted all changes made today that I know of, still nothing.

Neither did it help to disable/enable some plugins. At first I thought it'd be W3 Cache, but apparently it wasn't.

Essentially the payment options just keep reloading every time you select something and then it reverts back to the default one. As if it was going in a loop while loading.

**edit02:** There's also no difference between being logged in and not being logged in, but that much probably was obvious.

I'm at my wit's end here.

It's as if jQuery said "Nope. Not today, not anymore." And started doing that.

Comment: It seems like some JS issue. Do you use a plugin for the Cart/Checkout process?

Comment: Thank you! It was the stupid WooCommerce Jetpack Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the **WooCommerce Jetpack Plugin** all along. Stupid thing had something enabled which it didn't need. I guess that's what I get if I let a client access the plugin menu.

Thank you, denis.stoyanov, for helping me find the solution!